# Cannot build nsis installer with NSIS mui2

Tags: nsis

I want to build an installer with NSIS/MUI2. I prepared my own ui.exe so i am using this line of code in nsi file

```
!define MUI_UI my_ui.exe
```

I deleted the 103 directory dialog via Resource Hacker because i do not want it inside and nsis compiler complains that:

```
Error: Can't find IDD_DIR (103) in the custom UI!
```

How can i fix it? Where is this IDD_DIR defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDD_DIR` is dialog 103! It is the directory page. If you don't want a directory page in your installer, simply remove `Page Directory`/`MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY` from your script.

`IDD_DIR` is defined in [resource.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/NSIS/trunk/Source/exehead/resource.h).

Some dialogs and child controls are required, others can be deleted.

To "remove" a required child control you can make it hidden, disabled and/or move it to a negative position.